# Use Luks password for login?

Tags: luks, auto-login

I have the same password for my swap encryption and my login as main user. So it would be nifty to take the password from the boot-pw-dialogue to log in. Already the system uses the password to decrypt the other encrypted partitions, so it should be possible to take that password one step further to the login. Or asked the other way round:

Why do I have to enter the disk-encryption password and the user password although they are the same?

Comment: Because they're completely unrelated.

Comment: i dont see it that way. i.e. pam-mount can be used to decipher partitions using the login password, which is done for encrypted home folders or i.e. has to be done with iscsi - drives as in my ubuntu iscsi only mounts very late at startup, so those partitions cant be mounted using crypttab/fstab. and i dont see a reason why the service which takes the key from boot wouldn be able to pass it further on to login. another reason is that the login password has to be as strong as the device encryption key, so why not just use the same on single user systems. luks can handle multiple passwords.

Comment: You're confusing a decryption that happens when the OS is already loaded with the one that happens before the OS, let alone user login. And that's why they're totally unrelated.

Comment: there is no gap between boot and gui load, why shouldnt it be possible to pass a variable from from boot to the gui, as systemd is always continously running?

Comment: Good UX should not be prevented by shitty architecture. MacOS for example asks for the password, unlocks the encrypted disk, and logs in. I understand that Linux has multiple everything, that should work together nicely, but this is obviously a weak excuse to create great UX.
Similar is achievable in Linux though, but not with a single partition. If only the home partition is encrypted, Systemd can unlock it with the password used for logging in. But this leaves your core system unencrypted. Here's a guide for Arch. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Mounting_at_login